# Why I get a MissingIIdToken error when checking the FCM topic after uninstalling the app

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm creating push notifications using Firebase's fcm, but I don't know what causes the error to be displayed, so I would like to ask a question.

https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server?hl=ja
Referring to the above site, register fcm_token in the topic when installing the app,
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/info/TOKEN?details=true
We have confirmed that the results are returned correctly when executed using the above API.

```
Code: 200
Reason: OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"applicationVersion":"**","gmiRegistrationId":"**","application":"**","scope":"*","authorizedEntity":"**","rel":{"topics":{"hoge":{"addDate":"2023-12-28"}},"appSigner":"**","platform":"**"}
```

After that, if you uninstall the app and run the topic confirmation API again, you will see the following notation.

```
Code: 404
Reason: Not Found
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Body: {"error":"MissingIIdToken"}
```

Does this mean that once you uninstall it, the topic registration itself is cancelled?
If I send a push notification targeting a topic, will this be judged as not being targeted?

The best practice for token management is to unregister old tokens from topics, but I would appreciate it if you could let me know if this is the case.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-tokens?hl=en#unsubscribe_stale_tokens_from_topics